# What does 度量が知れる mean?

Tags: translation

For example here https://twitter.com/vladiii_ap_bot/status/321001378766000128. EPWING dictionary and Google search didn't help.

> 追従も度が過ぎると**度量が知れる**ぞ、ダーニック。余を領王と呼ぶお前は、我が主人でもある。余はサーヴァント、そのことを否定はせん

Comment: 度量: capacity. 知れる: to be (easily) known.

Comment: Do you have any idea what it means (from context)? Did you consult the dictionaries in our [resources list](http://meta.japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/756/resources-for-learning-japanese) to try to understand the different parts?

Comment: Obviously :"EPWING dictionary and Google search didn't help", breaking it down into parts didn't make any more sense to me. Every time I see this particular phrase it comes up as a fixed expression. If you have no idea either, no need to commend, though.

Answer (score 2):

元ネタは[これ](http://typemoon.wikia.com/wiki/Darnic_Prestone_Yggdmillennia)っぽい。

In this context, the speaker, as a Servant of Darnic, says Darnic should not be too obsequious to the speaker, although Dernic refers to the speaker as Lord (領王).

Someone's 度量 refers to their capacity, potential, tolerance, generosity, etc.

度量が知れる literally means something like "reveal one's capacity", and it is a set phrase usually used to point out someone's little-mindedness, petty-mindedness, incompetence, etc.